# Non-pointfree style is substantially slower

Tags: haskell, memoization

I have the following, oft-quoted code for calculating the nth Fibonacci number in Haskell:

```
fibonacci :: Int -> Integer
fibonacci = (map fib [0..] !!)
    where fib 0 = 0
          fib 1 = 1
          fib n = fibonacci (n-2) + fibonacci (n-1)
```

Using this, I can do calls such as:

```
ghci> fibonacci 1000
```

and receive an almost instantaneous answer.

However, if I modify the above code so that it's not in pointfree style, i.e.

```
fibonacci :: Int -> Integer
fibonacci x = (map fib [0..] !!) x
    where fib 0 = 0
          fib 1 = 1
          fib n = fibonacci (n-2) + fibonacci (n-1)
```

it is substantially slower. To the extent that a call such as

```
ghci> fibonacci 1000
```

hangs.

My understanding was that the above two pieces of code were equivalent, but GHCi begs to differ. Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

Comment: The first definition is more like `fibonacci = let k = map fib [0 ..] in \x -> k !! x`. It probably shares the list of results instead of recomputing it each time.

Comment: Mm, so I'm content that it's this "sharing" (memoization) that makes the first one super quick. But why do the same for the second one?

Comment: You are running your code in GHCI, without optimizations. Try compiling both functions with `-O2` and seeing if GHC is smart enough to solve your problem for you.

Comment: Update: compiling with optimizations and looking at the generated core shows it is *identical*. For future reference, if you are interested in performance, you *must* compile with optimizations!

Comment: @user2407038, I think the reason for the difference in the unoptimized code is interesting regardless.

Comment: Thanks, I should've compiled first... But as @dfeuer says, it'd be interesting to know why the unoptimised code acts the way it does.

Comment: @dfeuer I agree completely, which is why I left a comment instead of making it an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To observe the difference, you should probably look at Core. My guess that this boils down to comparing (roughly)

```
let f = map fib [0..] in \x -> f !! x
```

to

```
\x -> let f = map fib [0..] in f !! x
```

The latter will recompute `f` from scratch on every invocation. The former does not, effectively caching the same `f` for each invocation.

It happens that in this specific case, GHC was able to optimize the second into the first, once optimization is enabled.

Note however that GHC does not always perform this transformation, since this is not always an optimization. The cache used by the first is kept in memory forever. This might lead to a waste of memory, depending on the function at hand.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find it but struck out. I think I have it on my PC at home.
What I read was that functions using fixed point were inherently faster.
There are other reasons for using fixed point. I encountered one in writing this iterative Fibonacci function. I wanted to see how an iterative version would perform then I realized I had no ready way to measure. I am a Haskell neophyte. But here is an iterative version for someone to test.
I could not get this to define unless I used the dot after the first last function.
I could not reduce it further. the [0,1] parameter is fixed and not to be supplied as a parameter value.

```
Prelude> fib = last . flip take (iterate (\ls -> ls ++ [last ls + last (init ls)]) [0,1])
Prelude> fib 25
```

[0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946,17711,28657,46368,75025]